# Mail management with folders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I am trying to set up Outlook in order to be more productive in my day-to-day work. Since I work as a consultant, I have various engagements. For each of them, I created a separate folder in my Inbox and am using the "always move messages from the conversation" feature in order to have future emails redirected to the right folder.

I have three questions regarding this method:

1. When doing so, new emails automatically redirected to a folder using the aforementioned method do not trigger notification nor increment the unread counter, which could lead to some emails being missed. Is it possible to have mails in folders triggering the same notifications and being counted as part of the unread emails ?
2. When one of my assignments is completed, I need to remove the folder and its content for confidentiality reasons. BUT, if for any reason, I receive a mail from a thread that was redirected to the folder I just removed, it will automatically be redirected to the deleted folder, and hence, to the deleted elements folder, making it even worst in terms of visibility.
   Should manually select all messages from the folder and right click and deactivate the automated moving of the conversation to the folder before deleting said folder ?
3. More generally, the two above problems make me question myself regarding my email management solution. Is this a convenient way of proceeding ? I feel like what I need is in the end rather common, and I am sure there should be a quite standard / simple way of doing it.

In the end, here is a recap of what I would want to achieve:

- Have mails in folders per assignment
- Automatically move emails from an already moved conversation to the same folder without having to define complex rules
- Keep the same visibility on all new emails, whether they belong to a folder or not (yet)
- Being able to delete all mails in a folder (and ideally the folder itself) when an assignment is done, without having new emails redirected to my "deleted elements" folder in case someone reopens one of the mail thread after deletion of the folder

Thank you so much for any help, I hope this topic is not too broad, but I feel like these three questions kind of belong together in my case :)

Comment: It is a bit broad indeed, but you seem to have put some thought in it, hence the upvote. Could you perhaps indicate what you've tried so far in resolving point 1? Also, for point 3 there are many different ways which depend on personal taste. Perhaps you can focus this question on point 1 only? That seems to be the issue that brought you here. For point 2 you already have a solution, and 3 depends on personal preference.